# What is a better way to write "array.length - 1" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

Instead of using `array.length-1` to get the largest index of an array can you do some thing like this `array.largestIndex`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use JS getter to do this.

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'largestIndex', {
   get: function () {
      return (this.length == 0) ? null : this.length - 1
   }
});
```